# Sorting stacked bar chart based on the values ( highest to lowest) in Tableau

Tags: sorting, tableau-api, stacked-chart

I am using working on Tableau stacked bar chart.
The bar chart represents the total %. Therefore, the length of bar chart is equal.
Now I would like to sort the dimension (referee) based on the values of legends ( highest to lowest).
can anyone suggest me how to do it.
I also attached the packaged workfile [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11idJATwgsiIveIIq_sEObX2MFbrx5Ekv)
[image: Please see the picture here]

Here is the picture of sort screen;
[image: Sort Screen]

Level of data source below:
[image: Level of data]
Below is the screen shot based on the final answer provided:
[image: Final Look]

Thanks,

Zep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to get this you first need to get a calc field that gets the win %:

```
SUM(IF [FTR] = 'AWins' OR [FTR] = 'Hwins' THEN 1 END)/COUNTD([Game ID])
```

This can then be used to rank the referees:

[image]

Now the reason that it may not be working for you with your technique is that you're sorting on COUNTD(Wins) which is the total number of wins, not the percentage wins for the ref. So someone that has just played more games may come up higher in the rank

Now you have the calc field, you can go back to your report and sort on the new field:

[image]

I rearranged the legend so you can see that the ref with the best % wins are shown first (red and blue bars)

---

If you don't want it sorted by win %, then change the calc field to:

```
SUM(IF [FTR] = 'AWins' OR [FTR] = 'Hwins' THEN 1 END)
```

---

For the COUNTD of games, if you only have the date and the game available and want to create an ID from that that is unique, create a calc field like this:

```
game-date-id = STR([game]) + STR(' ') + STR(date)
```

This will then be used in your COUNTD if statement:

```
SUM(IF [FTR] = 'AWins' OR [FTR] = 'Hwins' THEN 1 END)/COUNTD([game-date-id])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for misunderstanding on the sorting. I like to sort the dimension(Referee) based on the value( Hwin). How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this the same way as I described? Did you try it?

Comment: For security reasons I can't download you workbook from Drive, but could you show me a picture (update your answer) with the output when you've tried my method?.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you can't get mine to work. So the measure in my picture is the % share of cities that urban vs rural, but i've sorted the bars based on the COUNTD of cities - a different measure. In the popup when you click sort you can click the measure and it opens a dropdown where you can choose the sorting measure

Answer (score 0):

[image: here is the pic]
I have attached the picture of the dashboard.
I want to sort the referee based of Hwin

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but could you show the report and not the dashboard? I want to look at the pills in the columns and rows. Please see my updated answer for a screenshot showing sorting down by clicking on a pill

Comment: No Worries. Thanks for the reply.
Please see the attached picture in the original post.

Comment: I can see in the picture that you're sorting on something for Referee, when you click on the downward facing arrow in the Rows section at the top (where you drag Referee) then click Sort, what field is selected?

Comment: How is COUNTDWin calculated? Is it in the format of COUNTD(IF [FTR] = AWin OR [FTR] = HWIN THEN [matchid] END)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. It did not work out as expected

Comment: Thank you so much and waiting for your answer.

Comment: What level of data is your source at? From the data source screen can you show me a example row? Do you have game Ids or another unique identifier? Did you create the field I suggested?

Comment: I only ask because I was able to create what you need with dummy data

Comment: I have added the level of data source.

Comment: Unique identifier would be combination of date and match.

Comment: So for the count distinct, make an ID field that's a string: STR([game]) + STR(' ') + STR(Date)       Then using that for the winners measure: SUM(IF [FTR] = 'AWins' OR [FTR] = 'Hwins' THEN 1 END)/COUNTD([NEW FIELD THAT YOU JUST CREATED BY CONCATENATING DATE AND GAME])

Comment: I'll add that to the bottom of my answer